# Greek characters in vectors, lists and data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, non-ascii-characters

Under the specs listed below, `data.frame` objects convert greek characters to latin equivalents when the table is printed. For instance,

```
w<-data.frame(A=c("σ", "a", "b"))
print(w)
#    A
# 1: s
# 2: a
# 3: b
```

The same happens if "σ" is replaced by "\U03C3".
`data.frame` seems to treat "σ" and "s" interchangeably:

```
w<-data.frame(σ=1:4)
w$σ
# [1] 1 2 3 4
w$s
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

But when it comes to printing, it favors the latin version.

However, vectors (together with lists) show a slightly different behaviour:

```
x=c("σ", "a", "b")
x
# [1] "s" "a" "b"
x=c("\U03C3", "a", "b")
x
# [1] "σ" "a" "b"
```

Is there a way, to force `data.frame` objects to print "σ" instead of "s"?

---

Output of

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

# Matrix products: default

# locale:
# [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252        LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       
# [5] LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252    

# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

# other attached packages:
# [1] openxlsx_4.1.0    data.table_1.11.4

# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
# [1] compiler_3.4.4 tools_3.4.4    Rcpp_0.12.19   zip_1.0.0
```

Comment: It prints here correctly for both "σ" and "\U03C3". Using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I don't see an "s" in the data (only a sigma) and I don't have a valid "s" column name. Please add your R version, operating system, and output from running `sessionInfo()`. Also, do base data frames do the same for you?

Comment: `w <- data.table::data.table(σ = 1:4);w$σ;w$s` returns `[1] 1 2 3 4` and `NULL` with locale: en_US.UTF-8.

Comment: @Spacedman, @markus This is interesting, I added the output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: With `data.frame` I reproduce exactly the same behaviour

Comment: I would rewrite your question with data frames rather than data tables since data frames are part of base R. Try simple vectors as well - does it do the same with them? ie if you do `x=c("σ", "a", "b")` does the first element print as `s` or sigma?

Comment: I followed your advice, thanks.